Is there a narrative gap within The Butterfly Effect by James Swallow?
I'm doing English Literature coursework (AQA exam board English Literature A-level) where we have to read a novel and then find a narrative gap within that novel, and then fill this gap in. I chose The Butterfly Effect and because of the complexity of the novel I am struggling. So any help would be good! I was thinking to explore perhaps Evan's mum's other babies and why and how did they die? And talk about the idea of Evan being a miracle baby. Perhaps those babies before him went through a similar thing (strangling themselves inside the uterus), or maybe I could explore Evan's father more and his condition, or even how he was when Evan was even younger (just born). Another idea could be the backstory of Tommy, Kayleigh or Lenny. I have ideas but I don't know how to explore them or what to particularly say about them in an essay.

Hi. Thanks for the question. Unfortunately, as it stands, it's not a great fit for the site: we focus on specific questions to which users can provide detailed, references answers. This is currently too broad and is more of a help request. It might help if you edit it to ask about one specific instance of what you feel is a "narrative gap" in the novel?

there's a narrative gap in every book. The main character arrives somewhere "the next day" without us being told how the evening went, how they slept, the process of eating and dressing the next morning. Do you understand what this essay will be marked on? Do you have to choose a gap that is somehow a "good" one to write about? Does it matter how much of the gap's content you make up out of whole cloth, and how much you infer from elsewhere in the book? Or could you get an A for considering just how the Big Bad Wolf got to Grandmother's house first? Knowing that will help you choose a gap.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. The examples you give are all narrative gaps. Any one of them, it seems, would be sufficient for your assignment. What sort of help are you looking for? Do you want us to pick one for you and tell you what to say about it? That seems a lot like asking us to do your homework, and I'm sure that's not your intent. But failing that, it is not clear what you're asking. Can you clarify? Thanks.
